# Find line and than find word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to know if is possible to find a line with regex.

For example, i have this text:

> I love apples and
>       I love banana an
>       I love juice and
>       I hate everything.

Could i say "RegExp, find the line 4, than in this line try to find 'everything', if if doesn't match, just return undefined'

I'm not trying to do like:

```
/I hate everything/
```

I want pass the line, a number.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you MUST use regex for this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you "have this text."  Is it in an array?  Continuous string?  Separate variables?  This reads like 4 random quoted strings with no variable assignment.  You need to clarify.  Show some code please.

Comment: Is a text with 4 lines

Comment: Yes, i'm learning regex haaha

Comment: You don't need regex for this, but if you're trying to learn regex I'd recommend **reading** some books/tutorials and utilize online testers such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) going off of trial and error instead of asking a question about applying regex when you don't really need it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could match a fixed count of newline characters (with whatever comes before them), then look for your text before the next newline:

```js
var strings = 'I love apples\nI love banana\nI love juice\nI hate everything';

alert(/(.*?\n){3}[^\n]*?everything/.test(strings))
```